# unescape html in spring jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

I want to unescape html chars in Spring JSP.

```
<c:out value="${fn:***unescapeHtml***(item.name)}" />
```

Is there an unescapeHtml or equivalent ?

Comment: If the string has characters like %20, %21 etc (for spaces, ! or :) it does not un-escape them. I use javascript escape to generate them at the first place.

Comment: Sorry, got what you were doing backwards--why are you using `escapeXml` if you're trying to **un**-escape?

Comment: Yeah, that was stupid, realised late. Now, how do I unescape ? edit ed question.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find a jsp tag to do the same, I had to resort to javascript method. That makes sense to me as I used javascript to escape at the first place, and it works fine.

I have put this into the $.ready() of the page.

```
$.find(xxxx) {
    $(this).text((unescape($(this).text())));
}
```